# why I am not allowed to participate in chat

Tags: bug, chat

I have enough reputation to add comments to protected questions and participate in chat. But I can't seem to do that . I see error messages like these everywhere. What can I do about it.

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam
>   answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10
>   reputation on this site.
>
> Welcome to The Stack Exchange Network chat! You'll need 20 reputation
>   to talk here. This site is moderated by the community, so please be
>   respectful of your fellow The Stack Exchange Network users. And while
>   you're at it, check out the FAQ!

Answer (score 1):

I see that your chat account is associated with your StackOverflow account. Try logging into chat from your StackOverflow account (using the "chat" link at the top of the page), choose the "all" Rooms tab, and then click on the [Mathematics chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) from there.

There may be difficulty finding which chat account is yours when trying to access chat from your math account directly. I've seen this occur before.